# Load torque required for driving lead screw

Tags: mechanical-engineering, motors, mechanisms, machine-design

I want to calculate motor torque for lead screw mechanism like this (horizontal)
[image]

I want equation to calculate this mechanism to find motor.
I use this equation https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oAxYvoVXDrI but I don't know is it correct.

Comment: Have you looked at similar questions on here?

Comment: I completely forgot about this. I'm going to go look for it now.

Comment: Yeah pretty sure this has been asked before. Just be aware that overconstraint in the linear travel mechanism vs leadscrew bearing mountings, can produce extra side forces, which you would barely feel on the guide rail, but will definitely have an additional effect at the leadscrew nut.

Comment: This [google "site" search](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fengineering.stackexchange.com%2F+load+torque+lead+screw) may reveal some candidates for a duplicate.